# Automatically insert bibliography before appendix

Tags: templates, etoolbox

I came up with a new problem by automate my document. The requirement is to insert a bibliography at the end of a document. Therefore I use `\AtEndDocument` from `etoolbox`. This is working perfectly fine as demonstrated in the mwe below.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\AtEndDocument{\printbibliography[type=article]}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \Blinddocument

    \nocite{*}

    % Appendix is optional
    % But the bibliography should be printed first
    \appendix
    \chapter{Last chapter after bibliography}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

But there is a second requirement, too. If there is a appendix, which is optional, the bibliography have to be **before** the appendix. Now there are two questions:

1. How can I test if there is a appendix within the document?
2. How can the bibliography automatically inserted before the appendix if there is a appendix. Otherwise if there is no appendix put the bibliography at the end of the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can patch the `\appendix` command to tell it to print the bibliography and set a flag/toggle if it did. You can then check for that flag in the `\AtEndDocument`.

[As explained in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443268/automatically-insert-bibliography-before-appendix/443273?noredirect=1#comment1112502_443273) `\pretocmd` makes sure that logically the bibliography is printed *before* the appendix, while `\apptocmd` would make the bibliography part of the appendix. You can see a clear difference between the two if you try the below with `\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]`. With `\apptocmd` the bibliography will be *Chapter A*, the first part of the appendix, with `\pretocmd` on the other hand it is *Chapter 2*, the last chapter of the main text.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newtoggle{appendixbib}
\pretocmd\appendix{\toggletrue{appendixbib}\printbibliography}{}{}
\AtEndDocument{\iftoggle{appendixbib}{}{\printbibliography}}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \Blinddocument

    \cite{sigfridsson}

    % Appendix is optional
    % But the bibliography should be printed first
    \appendix
    \chapter{Last chapter after bibliography}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm a bit torn whether or not I should think this is a good idea though. I think it should be a conscious decision where to place the bibliography. But on the other hand if there are simple rules like this, automating them seems attractive and even to the point of the separation of content and format.

Comment: At this point the rules are quite simple. Btw the user will get an option if one want to use this feature. As you said it provides a clear structure

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using \pretocmd instead of \apptocmd? (just for better unterstanding)

Comment: @faltfe You can see the difference between `\pretocmd` and `\apptocmd` when you use `\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]`. With `\pretocmd` the bibliography belongs to the main part of the document and is numbered as a normal chapter - it is printed before the appendix. With `\apptocmd` it is counted as the first chapter of the appendix and gets numbered accordingly - it is printed in the appendix. `\pretocmd` inserts its code argument before the original macro definition, `\apptocmd` appends it after the original definition.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It make it much more clearer for me.

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\AtEndDocument{\printbibliography[type=article]}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \Blinddocument

    \nocite{*}

    % Appendix is optional
    % But the bibliography should be printed first

\printbibliography[heading=none]

    \appendix
    \chapter{Last chapter after bibliography}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought the idea would be to make that happen automatically. This just (manually) prints a bibliography without heading and again one at the end.

Comment: I'm sorry but your solution isn't what I aked for. The idea is to let it happen automatically without further user interaction.